# python: trying to plot a bar graph

Tags: python

My code keeps coming back with this error whenever I am trying to plot a bar chart and I can't work out how to fix it. Can someone please help?

This is the error message and I have tried loads of different things to try and fix it but nothing is working.

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.3\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2118, in bar
if h < 0:

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

and this is my code which I am using

```
country = []
population = []
per_clean_wat = []

with open('clean_water.csv','r') as cleanwater:
    cleanwater = csv.reader(cleanwater)
    for row in cleanwater:
        c, p, pcw = row
        country.append(c)
        population.append(p)
        per_clean_wat.append(pcw)

c_p = []

for i in range(171):
    population[i] = str(float(population[i])).zfill(6)
    c_p.append([country[i],population[i]])

c_p = sorted(c_p,key=lambda tup:tup[1], reverse=True)

c_px = []
c_py = [] 

for i in range(10):
    c_px.append(c_p[i][0])
    c_py.append(c_p[i][1])

print(c_px)
print(c_py)

plt.margins(0.2)
plt.xticks(list(range(1,len(c_py)+1)),c_px,rotation='vertical',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Population (in millions)')
plt.title('10 most populous countries')
plt.bar(range(1,len(c_py)+1),c_py,align='center',color='green')
```

when I run it, it doesn't print the data on the graph.

Comment: It doesn't work because `c_py` is a list of string

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed it and it's working now

Comment: Should I write an answer ?

Comment: It's ok, I got it